# How to handle errors with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am looking for advice on what the best way to do error handling the vue-router. I have implemented an error boundary component to catch global errors in my application, however this doesn't work with the vue-router since it's not part of the Vue.js life cycle. I have navigation guards that gets data from an API, in the event this fails how would handle this failure?

Comment: You can use a Vuex store to add and handle your errors. This will work in your case

Comment: How do go by removing the error in Vuex after? Are you clearing Vuex on every button click?

Answer (score 0):

if no such route exists add a wildcard route:

```
routes = [..
  { path: "/:pathMatch(.*)", redirect: { name: "whois" } },
]
```

If you wish to handle errors not only on every [push](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-failures.html#detecting-navigation-failures)  but router wide, install a [router wide error handler](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/router.html#onerror)

```
    router.onError(err => {
       print('<!-- router error: ' + err.message + ' -->')
    })
```